# comparing input Date & Time with current date & time in android

Tags: android, date, time, notifications

I am creating a "To-do Things" app where a user can create tasks to be done. In the Main activity I have a fragment which consists of three EditTexts ie Notification Content , Date & Time of notification.

Each new entry is added to a database. This database is displayed in form of ListView in another activity.

My Questions are-:
Q1) I want to compare date & time of each entry & print only those which are about to come ie whose date & time is after the present date & time.So how should I perform the comparison?

Q2) When the date & time is reached generate a notification .

Answer (score 0):

Q1) Use the [Calendar](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html) class. You can take a Calendar object and set its date and time with your user data (using Calendar.set) and then compare with another calendar which you set to the current time as follows:

```
Calendar cal = GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
cal.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
```

To compare two calendars you can use the Calendar.before method, or you can convert them back into "timeInMillis" and calculate the difference in milliseconds.

Q2) Use the[AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) and a BroadCastReceiver